# Cable cut on immobilisers?

Tags: immobilizer

I have heard of the 'cable cut' principle for immobilisers but have also heard that this can be detected by car thieves with equipment. Does anyone know what this is?

I am looking at this immobiliser for my car but not sure if "cuts" cables?

https://www.pandoracaralarm.com/catalog/accessories/blockage-radio-relays/pandora-rr-101.html

Thanks

Comment: It’s you who cuts the cables when fitting.

Comment: @SolarMike - I believe the OP is asking about the type of alarm, whether it requires the installer to cut the cables or if it installs inline (using factory connections) to install without having to hack on the wiring harness, not who does the cutting.

Comment: The provided link looks to be a solid state relay thats part of a larger system. So if by “cut” you mean the circuit is open by default, than yes.